# Windows setup project - can I specify location of the application in the start menu?

Tags: windows, installation

I have added a setup project to my .net windows application (VS 2008), and when I install my application I get a menu item in the start menu for my application at the top level of the start menu.  I would like the user to be able to select a folder for the application during installation like I've seen with most applications, but I can't see how to do this.  Is it possible using a windows setup project?

Answer (score 1):

On your startup project, right click and choose View->File System
Click the parent Node "File System on Target Machine."
Right Click, and choose Add
You can then access the "Users Start Menu"

This will let you specify a location to put it.

You can then use the User Interface screen to "Add a Dialog" to the install process.

Here you should be able to wire it up that they can select a location, and pass that information to the "Users Start Menu" dialog.

Although, I've never done it so I can't go into details.

Comment: So are you saying this is something that requires some custom code and isn't a built-in capability of the setup project?

Comment: Not sure if it requires custom code or not, but there is a folder for the "Users Start Menu"  The custom part might be setting in folder A instead of the default folder B.